# Someone know if this site is a scam?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

i want to know if i can buy in this site, they offer also a money back guarantee.
http://hiddencrztrqz2h6bjito56pzdamwvhwssnhhghfvumfebuk5aejtlad.onion/
If someone has already buy from this site or know that it is a scam please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Or if someone know a good place for buying hardware for my pc on dark web

Answer (score 2):

> Or if someone know a good place for buying hardware for my pc on dark web

Please, do not buy hardware on the DarkWeb. It is mostly scam and when not, it is stolen property and buying it is not a good idea. Best, non-scam, up to date links you can find at http://darkfailllnkf4vf.onion/ (I don't vouch for this site, neither any sites by this link, information is solely for education, usage of anything by the link is solely your responsibility).

Best of luck.